# Can Scorching Ray inflict Sneak Damage multiple times on the same target?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, sneak-attack

The feat Manyshot makes it clear that it only applies precision-based damage once (for one of the arrows).

Since Scorching Ray does not have that description, and all of its rays can aim at the same target, can it inflict multiple times of precision-based damage on the same target?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yeah, a duplicate. Thanks for noting that. I won't be able to find it by myself.